# increment php variable in javascript

Tags: javascript, php, variables

I am trying to increment a php variable in a javascript function:

```
function border(){
  <?php $var_drafts_display=0; ?>;
  for(var i=0; i<5; i++)
     {
    <?php ++$var_drafts_display ; ?>;
     }
  var final_num='<?php  echo $var_drafts_display; ?>';
  alert(final_num);
  }
```

But the php variable gets incremented only once i.e `alert(final_num)` shows 1. I know php is server side program and javascript is client side program, is that the main problem why php variable is not getting incremented. Also, I am not able to figure out why it is getting incremented only once.

Comment: You cannot increment a php variable in javascript without ajax. Your javascript is just text to php. You need to understand the difference between server side and client side code, and how they interact.

Answer (score 6):

You're trying to mix server side code (PHP) with JavaScript code:

```
function border(){
  <?php $var_drafts_display=0; ?>;
  for(var i=0; i<5; i++)
     {
    <?php ++$var_drafts_display ; ?>;
     }
  var final_num='<?php  echo $var_drafts_display; ?>';
  alert(final_num);
  }
```

will ultimately get turned into this:

```
function border(){
      ;
      for(var i=0; i<5; i++)
         {
        ;
         }
      var final_num='1';
      alert(final_num);
      }
```

which will simply alert 1.

You'd want to do something like:

```
function border(){
    var draftsToDisplay = <?php echo $var_drafts_display=0; ?>;
    for(var i=0; i<5; i++)
    {
        draftsToDisplay++;
    }
    alert(draftsToDisplay);
}
```

There is a great guide on the differences between client/server code, and some examples [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13840429/what-is-the-difference-between-client-side-and-server-side-programming).

Comment: Thanks...:) now I understood why I was getting one in alert

Answer (score 2):

That kind of behavior is impossible. You need to clearly understand, how php and js works. PHP just compile web page html code on a server side and then it pass html code to a client. Client's web browser parsing that code and then execute all scripts. So your js machine will see the next code:

```
function border(){
      for(var i=0; i<5; i++)
         {
         }
      var final_num='1';
      alert(final_num);
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you displaying all iterations in individual alert box then you can do this:

```
function border(){
  <?php $var_drafts_display=0; ?>;
   var final_num = 0;
   for(var i=0; i<5; i++){
    <?php $var_drafts_display++ ; ?>;
    final_num='<?php  echo $var_drafts_display; ?>';
    alert(final_num);
  } 
}
```